# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this function? I cant figure it out

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to make sure the textbox is not left blank and has at least one letter, that is checked from beginning to end. (validation) HELP?

```
function checkCity()
{
    var reg_exp=/^[a-z]{1, }$/i; 

    if (reg_exp.test(document.getElementById("city").value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Check city field. It has error.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It would be useful if you showed what `document.getElementById('city').value` returned. Could you do that? See [ask] for more tips on asking useful questions,

Comment: Edit the post to explain what you expected, and what you got, from calling your code. Minimal, complete examples.

Comment: I got nothing when running the current code. No alert or anything. I have to validate the form to make sure the user input their first name,last name, address, ctiy, zipcode, and email. i have the first 3 correct but it will not validate anything past the address box because something is wrong with the code for "city" input.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space after the comma in your repetition quantifier. You really want the following (notice there's no space after the `1,` in the curly braces):

```
var reg_exp=/^[a-z]{1,}$/i;
```

Or, you could do, which is the same:

```
var reg_exp=/^[a-z]+$/i;
```

---

Further, your expression--even when fixed--doesn't actually find **"not left blank and has at least one letter"** from your question but, rather, *only letters from start to finish*. If you really wanted "*not left blank and has at least one letter*" then that is simply `/[a-z]/i` since a string that passes that expression has at least a single letter and, since it has a letter, it cannot be blank.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but still same result. I get nothing, no alert, or anything. Cant figure it out for the life of me! Bout to give up!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your regex to this:

```
var reg_exp = /^[a-z]+$/i;
```

Comment: This didnt help either jim. Not sure what else to do. There must be an error somewhere else in my code.